# Changing Color of the Legend Text using Achartengine (Pie chart)

Tags: android, achartengine

I have created Pie chart using Achartengine. Here, i can't able to change the color of the LEGEND TEXT , the text displays with the color of the legend icon .

we can able to change the label text color but not legend text color. Can any one help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The legend item color is inherited from the series rendering color. In order to change that, you need to change the color for the series.